# How to copy dependencies with Docker?

Tags: .net, docker, asp.net-web-api

I am new to Docker. I am trying to Docker-ize my .NET Web API. My IDE (Rider) automatically created the following Dockerfile for me. When I try to execute `docker build -t my-api .` in the terminal, the process fails to copy the Core, DependencyResolution, Common, and Data .csproj files. I get an error that says **"failed to compute cache key '/Infrastructure.Common/Infrastructure.Common.csproj' not found"**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApi/WebApi.csproj", "WebApi/"]
COPY ["Core/Core.csproj", "Core/"]
COPY ["DependencyResolution/DependencyResolution.csproj", "DependencyResolution/"]
COPY ["Infrastructure.Common/Infrastructure.Common.csproj", "Infrastructure.Common/"]
COPY ["Infrastructure.Data/Infrastructure.Data.csproj", "Infrastructure.Data/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApi/WebApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApi"
RUN dotnet build "WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.WebApi.dll"]
```

My project is structured like so:

MyApp.WebApi

- Core
- DependnecyResolution
- Infrastructure.Common
- Infrastructure.Data
- WebApi

  - Dockerfile

And I am executing `docker build -t my-api .` while my current directory is `/WebApi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Dockerfile is created in a way that it assumes that the *context* is the directory above the `WebApi` directory.

The last parameter on the `docker build` command is the context. Right now it's `.` which is the current directory. Change it to `..` to make it the directory above, so you have

```
docker build -t my-api ..
```

Comment: Wow. Amazing. Yep, that was it! Thank you so much! I had to specify my Dockerfile manually but this bit of knowledge solved my problem! My command ended up being `docker build -t my-api -f Dockerfile ..`